# Android GetExtra causing application to crash

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using getExtra which is causing the application to crash.

In my activity with button click I am using this code

```
String test1ID = "test1ID";
Intent intenttesting1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);                      
intenttesting1 .putExtra("Test1", test1ID);
startActivity(intenttesting1 );
```

and then in MyActivity I am using the following code to get the intent

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    if(extras.getString("Test1").equals("test1ID")){ // if an extra has been set
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1 Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.

I have another button which I want to use to similar with but to send a different string.
However doing so causes the application to crash.

```
 String test2ID = "test2ID";
 Intent intenttesting2 = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);                      
 intenttesting2 .putExtra("Test2", test2ID);
 startActivity(intenttesting2 );

 Bundle 2extras= getIntent().getExtras();
 if(2extras!= null){
     if(2extras.getString("Test2").equals("test2ID")){ // if an extra has been set
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1 Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Are we not able to send 2 different intent extras to the same activity?

Not sure what I am doing wrong, as both sets of code work, but only 1 set works at one time or the app crashes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace from the crash?

Comment: post the logcat details

Comment: "Are we not able to send 2 different intent extras to the same activity?" what do you mean by this?

Comment: Hi, this is the log cat details

Comment: You are not supposed to check if the extras `Bundle` is null, but whether the extra `String` is null.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I got it working. I was using the on Click listener on the same button instead of 2 different buttons.

Comment: @AndroidLearner then you have accepted the wrong answer. post your answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [yoda notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to protect against null pointer dereference when using `.equals`

```
Bundle 2extras= getIntent().getExtras();
if(2extras!= null) {
   if("test2ID".equals(2extras.getString("Test2"))){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1 Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should be used this for this situation

String test1ID = "test1ID";
Intent intenttesting1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);                      
intenttesting1 .putExtra("Test1", test1ID);
startActivity(intenttesting1 );

for next activity
 if("test2ID".equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("Test1"))){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1 Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```